# Elasticsearch bulk api : read time out in Java

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to post bulk data to AWS Elasticsearch 5.1.1 by using bulk api.
I am using simple http client to execute the post request in java.
I am posting bulk data using file.

Maximum file size : 1 MB
Maximum elasticsearch requests : 300 in single file
HTTP request timeout : 60 seconds

However I am getting following exception

```
Could not execute HttpPost. Reason: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

and sometimes

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting *max_content_length* 
If you are doing parallel hits, try to find out sweet spot
refer : - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html